# Read and Write file from MS Azure using Python

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark

I am newbie to Python and Spark, I am trying to load file from Azure to table. Below is my simple code.

```js
import os
import sys
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.74"
sys.path.append("C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python")
sys.path.append("C:\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.1-src.zip")
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import *
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")


def loadFile(path, rowDelimeter, columnDelimeter, firstHeaderColName):
 
  
    loadedFile = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat",
                                      "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
                                      conf={"textinputformat.record.delimiter": rowDelimeter})
 
    
    rddData = loadedFile.map(lambda l:l[1].split(columnDelimeter)).filter(lambda f: f[0] != firstHeaderColName)
        
    return rddData


Schema= StructType([
    
    StructField("Column1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Column2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Column3", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Column4", StringType(), True)
        
        

])

rData= loadFile("wasbs://Storagename@Accountname.blob.core.windows.net/File.txt",
                     '\r\n',"#|#","Column1")
DF = sc.createDataFrame(Data,Schema)
DF.write.saveAsTable("Table1")
```

I am getting error like FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Did you use the Azure SparkHDinsight? Meanwhile, Could you please let me know which row in your code throw this error message?

Answer (score 0):

@Miruthan,
As far as I know, If we'd like to read data from WASB into Spark, the URL syntax is as following :

```
wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>
```

Meanwhile, due to Azure Storage Blob (WASB) is used as the storage account associated with an HDInsight cluster.Could you please double check it? Any update, please let me know.